# Getting Intraday Stock Data via Excel Add-in with Stock ISIN using =BDH() Function

Tags: excel, excel-formula, bloomberg

I wanted to extract intraday data for my research and I intend to use the following function to extract data at a 5 minutes frequency for a set of stocks. Does the following BDH function work?

```
=BDH("ISIN","OPEN","1/1/2023 0:00:00AM","1/7/2023 0:00:00AM","BarTp=T","BarSz=5")
```

Also, I intend to replicate this function for about 600 stocks, varying the first argument of the BDH function as a cell reference to the cell above, which contains its ISIN. Please ask me questions if this not clear.

The reason why I am asking here and not simply testing at a Bloomberg Terminal is because I only have an hour next week to extract some data, so I want to be quick and precise with it.

I have not tried it yet, but I hope this is a sufficient working function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few notes:

- if XYZ is the ISIN of the security, your formula should be `=BDH("XYZ ISIN"...)`
- dates are in US format, so this would retrieve 5-minute bars from Jan 1st to July 1st
- maximum available intraday history is around 6 months, so if you start earlier than January 2023 the data will probably only start in January

Other than that you should be fine.

Comment: Hi assylias, your answer is great. I have considered the first two points. Thank you, 6 months is fine. Also, does the function work for 10, 15, 20 and 30 minutes as well?

Comment: yes, just change the BarSz parameter